# Taking user input in a string of array and increment the string array inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am new to Java and I am trying to write a simple program that asks the subject names and calculate the total and average, the problem is I want to take user input as String array and print the names of subjects enter by user.

Here is my program im just writing the array input problem here:

```
public class SimpleSamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] subjects = new String[5];

        int subjectCount = 0;

        String subjectsName;

        if(subjectCount <= 5)
        {
            subjectsName = userInput.nextLine();
            subjects[subjectCount] = subjectsName;
            subjectCount+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

But its only printing one subject and program stops, it simply doesn't increments the array elements (subjects to be entered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(subjectCount <= 5){
  ...
  }
```

is executed once. It should be a loop and you should replace `5` by `4` if you want to execute it `5` time as `subjectCount` starts from `0`:

```
 while(subjectCount <= 4){
   ...
 }
```

or more simple and readable use a loop as the iteration count is known :

```
for (int subjectCount=0; subjectCount<subjects.length; subjectCount++){
      subjects[subjectCount] = userInput.nextLine();
 }
```

Comment: thanks, and whoops that was a silly mistake how could i didn't noticed!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `if` condition it simply checks the condition if true means execute the code.That's why it is executing only once.

Here You should use loop like `while,for`. And always array index start with **0** so change the condition as

```
while(subjectCount < 5)
```

For printing 5 times.

Updated code

```
public class SimpleSamples {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] subjects = new String[5];

    int subjectCount = 0;

    String subjectsName;

    while(subjectCount < 5)
    {
        subjectsName = userInput.nextLine();
        subjects[subjectCount] = subjectsName;
        subjectCount+=1;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following modification

```
public class SimpleSamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] subjects = new String[5];

        int subjectCount = 0;

        String subjectsName;

for(int i=0;i<subjects.size();i++){
 if(subjectCount <= 5)
        {
            subjectsName = userInput.nextLine();
            subjects[subjectCount] = subjectsName;
            subjectCount+=1;
        }
}

    }
}
```